# Frequency function in OpenOffice 4.1.2 Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I want to change the"data" field dynamically to 1 of 18 array names
example:

```
=frequency(LG_1;FOCUS)
```

where `LG_1` is the name of 1 of the 18 arrays, and `FOCUS` is the name of the classes array which stays constant.

Can this be done, i.e. can I insert via a `vlookup` or `hlookup` function?

Answer (score 0):

Lookups  work with a single value result or as an array.

It "may" be possible with an array which is generated below the entered formula... but I doubt it will accept a lookup for a name when it expects values, although you think it should be possible.

Comment: Tony  Thanks for the quick response. Isn't the purpose of Insert>Names>Define to substitute a name for a cell or array? I know it works if I substitute the array name (like LG_1) into frequency(data... field by using Insert>Names>Define, but I would like to do it dynamically. Bob